# Is it possible to perfectfly fit this particular modal content (not a picture) using window.open?

Tags: javascript

[This example](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_modal_tab) shows how to open a modal whose html code belongs to the parent.

What if this modal is in separate html page. Can I use `window.open` but resize it to adapt to the size of the content even in responsive mode?

If not possible, what best alternative in html5?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work. SO isn't an advice forum, it's for troubleshooting your code.

Comment: You could load the content of an HTML template asynchronously with JavaScript and then inject it into the DOM. You should maybe specify, what libraries you are already using (jQuery, Angular, etc.)